# sqoop error : java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for BigDecimal

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

Hi I am trying to import two table data from mysql to hdfs using sqoop command.

command :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://16.166.242.179:3306/organisation --username root -P --table emp --m 2 --boundary-query "select * from emp,dept where emp.deptno=dept.deptno" --target-dir /sqoop/output
```

error :

> ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for BigDecimal 'CLARK' in column 2.

Comment: You try to put in a numeric field a source field string (with value CLARK). Post some rows of your source

Comment: 7369 | SMITH   | CLERK     | 7902 | 1980-12-17 |  800.00 |    NULL |   20   
 7499 | ALLEN   | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 1981-02-20 | 1600.00 |  300.00 |     30